# Is there a way to find if the site is using shared hosting

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting

Is there a way to find if the site is using shared hosting hosting or not?

Comment: Curious why you'd want to know this.

Comment: @Su' , there are many cases that customers may not know what their short-term partner have ordered for host (where they want to keep the profit for themselves) or there are competitions in public sectors that representative officers may not have access to hosting to see if it is shared or not as should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a reverse IP lookup and see how many other websites run on the same IP:

Something like: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/

Comment: Multiple sites on an IP doesn't tell you it's shared hosting. You can do that with any VPS/dedicated setup.

Comment: Well it's a lot of assuming as well of course, the only things that are going to obscure it are things like load balencers.

You may have a few websites on one dedicated or vps server of course, but if theres 50 websites it's a good example if they are! - it's the best you're really going to get!

Comment: My intent wasn't to invalidate your response, just point out it's not true *enough* to toss out with no disclaimer. That 50 in your comment doesn't inherently tell you anything, either. As a possible method of investigating, this is fine. As an unqualified **answer**, it's misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily with any surety.
You can do some poking around to figure out what host a site is using, its IP and even what server that resolves to(eg. web152.example.com), but beyond that, you'd need specific knowledge about the host to know whether that particular server setup was shared, VPS, etc. The obvious exception is if it ends up at a host that *only* does one type of hosting, of course.